# How to control width of a long LaTeX equation in bookdown

Tags: latex, bookdown, gitbook

I have an `align` equation that does not fit into my `bookdown`, especially the `tag` I am using:

[image]

My `output` is `bookdown::gitbook`. It works in R `markdown` though:

```
---
title: "LaTeX"
output: html_document
---

# Long Equation

This is too long 

$$ \begin{align}
\text{outcome} &= f(\text{explanatory}) + \text{noise} \tag{Generic statistical model} \\
\text{outcome} &= \text{intercept} + \text{slope} \cdot \text{explanatory} + \text{noise} \tag{Generic linear model} \\
\end{align}$$
```

[image]

What is the difference between `markdown` and `bookdown` in handling LaTeX equations? And how to control the width of the aligned equations? Can I shift the entire formula block to the left?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `div` tag with margin right property.

```html
<div style="margin-right:400px;">
\begin{align}
\text{outcome} &= f(\text{explanatory}) + \text{noise} \tag{Generic statistical model} \\
\text{outcome} &= \text{intercept} + \text{slope} \cdot \text{explanatory} + \text{noise} \tag{Generic linear model} \\
\end{align}
</div>
```

Result:
[image]